# Plugin is too old,please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERIDE

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Strangely I am getting this error in Android Studio. It was not happening before. As far as I know,I might need to update gradle version to a new one.

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set   ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

This is my **build.gradle(Project:My project name goes here)** file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and **build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my project goes here"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Any ideas how to update the gradle version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

Currently, you have an alpha build that is non-official being used. Switch to something part of the official releases.

You should also control your build tools and other items in the top build.gradle and NOT in the module build file as shown.

Put this in your top project gradle.build as without it you don't ensure that all of the modules will be compiled compatibly and now you have to manage that individually.

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
    supportV4 = 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alpha 6 was just recently released, so try updating to

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6`

and see if that solves it.

Comment: I had to use         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
to make it work! Basically,I used a lower version of gradle!

Comment: That makes sense, I'm not too familiar with the gradle alpha channels, but you should always use the latest stable version unless you specifically want to try the alpha features